# using database dates in datepicker in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a datepicker which needs some dates to block. I need to fetch the date from database. The below script is working fine.

```
var disabledDates = ["2017-11-28", "2017-11-14", "2017-11-21"];

$(function () {
    $('.dtpkr').datepicker(
        {dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        appendText: '(dd/mm/yy)',
        showOn: 'both',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date)
            return [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1]                    
        }
    });
})
```

I am using following code to bring dates from database.

```
string date_query = "select display_date from X where display_type='static'";
DataTable dt = objDUT.GetDataTable(date_query);
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    arrayList.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
}

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jsr = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter jtw = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(sw);
jsr.Serialize(jtw, arrayList);

string jsArrayJSON = sw.ToString();
```

I am getting the dates like

```
12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM
12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

but I want to have the dates like `["2017-11-28", "2017-11-14", "2017-11-21"]`

how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean you want them joined in a single line, with a comma separator? Or you just want to remove the time portion?

Comment: I want like this ["2017-11-28", "2017-11-14", "2017-11-21"]; comma separator removing the time portion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is the issue.  It's explicitly converting what's probably a date or datetime field in your `DataTable` to a string.

Instead, explicitly convert it to a `DateTime`, and then use `string.Format()` or string interpolation to convert it to a string in the proper format.

string.Format():

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    arrayList.Add(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.DateTime(dt.Rows[i][0]));
}
```

String interpolation:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    arrayList.Add("{Convert.DateTime(dt.Rows[i][0]):MM/dd/yyyy}");
}
```